# Как вывести данные с бд на страницу?

Tags: php, sql

Есть у меня таблица  - http://prntscr.com/mpj28g
Надо с нее вывести все товары по очереди на страницу в видео такого html -

```
<div class="b-poster">
    <div class="coast lpsn">тутценаизбд<i>руб.</i></div>
    <div class="title">
        <p>тут_название_и_збд</p>
    </div>
    <a href="/item/2"><img src="туткартинкаизбд" width="188" height="108"></a>
</div>
```

вот как я работаю с бд - http://prntscr.com/mpj3gm

В идеале должно получиться так - http://prntscr.com/mpj42b

Answer (score -2):

Создаешь переменную

```
<?php 
$game = mysqli_query($connect , "SELECT * FROM `названиетаблицы` ]);
$chtoto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($game);
 ?>
```

Далее просто берешь значения из этой переменной. Например:

```
<?php 
echo 'Цена $chtoto['price']'; 
?>
```

Comment: Если нужно поподробней , напиши , я объясню

Comment: Что не так то ?